# How can I configure Spring Security to use custom AuthenticationManager implementation?

Tags: java, spring-security

What I have is:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="securityService"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

As I understand, the default AuthenticationManager implementation is used. I need to override its method `authenticate`. Is there a way to provide my own AuthenticationManager implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify a `customAuthenticationProvider` first, like this:-

```
<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="your.project.CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    ...
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Then, your custom authentication provider can extends Spring Security's AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider where you can place your custom authentication code.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    ...
}
```

Comment: which all (minimum) methods needs to be written in `CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl`?